# Receiving "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm attempting to return a set of attributes for a given "account" for a specific month. The account is defined as a concatenation of three attributes. My code is below. The sub-query itself is functional when run alone but does not work when used in both the SELECT and WHERE clauses. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to run the query. If there is a way to modify this query so it returns any/all applicable records that would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Error Message**:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:
*Action:

```
SELECT 
MONTH_KEY,
(
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST (NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_1
|| SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_2),-10,10)
|| SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_3),-10,10) AS VARCHAR(32)) 
FROM TABLE)
)
AS DERIVED_ATTRIBUTE,
NAME,
ANOTHER_VARIABLE
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST (NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_1
|| SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_2),-10,10)
|| SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_3),-10,10) AS VARCHAR(32)) 
FROM TABLE)
)
 =  (12345678900000000010000000001)
AND MONTH_KEY = (201903)
;
```

**Edit:**
Thank you @Ankit Bajpai. Your suggested code works perfectly and returns one record for all specified concatenated "DERIVED_ATTRIBUTE"s that I input.

Comment: Please show us the entire query.

Comment: Run the WHERE clause subquery standalone and see how many rows it returns.

Comment: the scalar subquery (the (SELECT ...) statements in your SELECT clause - aliased as DERIVED_ATTRIBUTE) is returning more than 1 row.

Comment: If @Ankit Bajpai provided a solution which helped you please consider [upvoting and/or accepting their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepted answers improve the quality of this site for other Seekers. Even just say *thanks* as a **comment** on the answer, which is clearer than an edit embedded in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select the same table thrice as you are already selecting the data from TABLE. You may try below query -

```
SELECT MONTH_KEY
      ,CAST(NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_1 ||
            SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_2),-10,10) ||
            SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_3),-10,10) AS VARCHAR(32)) AS DERIVED_ATTRIBUTE
      ,NAME
      ,ANOTHER_VARIABLE
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAST (NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_1 ||
            SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_2),-10,10) ||
            SUBSTR((10000000000 + NUMBER_ATTRIBUTE_3),-10,10) AS VARCHAR(32)) =  (12345678900000000010000000001)
AND MONTH_KEY = 201903
```